# Выборка данных SQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Есть таблицы с такими полями

**user**

- id
- login
- password

**task**

- id
- title

**complete**

- user_id
- task_id
- time

Нужно получить список всех заданий, из них определить, какие выполненые пользователем, а какие - нет. Пытался написать вот это:

```
SELECT
task.id AS id,
task.title AS title,
complete.use_tip AS free_tip,
complete.use_paid_tip AS paid_tip,
(complete.task_id IS NOT NULL) AS complete
FROM task LEFT JOIN complete ON task.id=complete.task_id where 
complete.user_id=3
```

[image: выборка]

Но выдаёт только кол-во заданий, которые выполнены пользователем. Если у меня 10 заданий, и пользователь с id=2 выполнил только два, то должна производиться выборка всех 10-ти заданий, а не двух

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось довольно быстро:

```
SELECT
task.id AS id,
task.title AS title,
complete.use_tip AS free_tip,
complete.use_paid_tip AS paid_tip,
(complete.task_id IS NOT NULL) AS complete
FROM task LEFT JOIN complete ON (task.id=complete.task_id AND complete.user_id=3)
```